# Some problems in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

So there is this one problem in real analysis that I think I have solved but do not know if it is correct as I might have solved it with just manipulation of theorem, for instance here is the problem:

**Problem:** $$\int_o^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}=\frac{1\times3\times \cdots \times (2n-1)}{2\times 4\times\cdots \times 2n}$$

**My solution:** We first observe that for $0<a<b<\infty$ we can define some $ \lambda:(o,\infty)\times[a,b]$ by $\lambda(x,k)=\frac{1}{k+x^2},\forall k\in[a,b]$,  is continuous hence it is measurable. Now we know after computing the first partial derivative:
$$\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial k}=\frac{-1}{(k+x^2)^2} \forall (x,k)\in(0,\infty)\times[a,b]$$ hence we also have:
$$\bigg|\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial k}(x,k)\bigg|\le \frac{1}{a(a+x^2)} $$ and we can observe:
$$\int_{(0,\infty)}\bigg|\frac{1}{a(a+x^2)}\bigg|dx=\frac{1}{a}\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{a+x^2}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{\pi}{2}a^{-0.5}<\infty$$

From here we get:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(k+x^2)^2}=-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\frac{1}{k+x^2}dx=-\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\int_o^{\infty}\frac{1}{k+x^2}dx=-\frac{d}{dk} \frac{\pi}{2}k^{-0.5}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi}{2}k^{-1.5}$$

Then repeatedly differentiating, we have:
$$\bigg|\frac{\partial^n\lambda}{\partial k^n}(x,k)\bigg|\le\frac{1}{a^n(a+x^2)}$$
$$\int_o^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(k+x^2)^{n+1}}=\frac{1\times3\times \cdots \times (2n-1)}{2\times 4\times\cdots \times 2n}\frac{\pi}{2}k^{-n-0.5}$$

Then simply take $k=1$, thus we have the wanted result. Now this is what I have done, but is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: The standard way to do this uses the calculus of residues in complex analysis

Comment: It is like I asked to see from the experienced if my solution looks correct ( and hope to get some feedback), but you suggest another method which I may or may not know seems rather puzzling.

Comment: I could be missing something obvious, but you have you gone from $\frac{1}{(a^2+x^2)^2}$ to $\frac{1}{a(a+x^2)}$?

Comment: O yes that was my typo, I have edited it now.

Comment: Your caculation of first partial derivative of $\lambda $ is wring.